# When to use the Flag module versus a boolean field?

Tags: entities, flags

In terms of performance, maintenance, and future expansion/migration, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using the **[Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)** module versus a **boolean field**?

In my case I would use the module to mark articles in a newspaper website that will be featured on the front page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular use case, you could go with the **field**. There is no need to install a contrib module for something that a field can do fine.

**Flags** create a new entity for each new flag you create. This adds an extra layer of complexity when you are need to migrate or deploy.

It would make sense to use flags, if for example, you wished that your each of your users could mark this article (eg mark it as favorite)

Drupal also offers the 'promote to front page' functionality that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features of the Flag module is per-user flags (useful for things like bookmarking, flagging as spam, etc). If you don't need this functionality, a single value checkbox (boolean) field would work fine to make articles for inclusion on a home page. Fields are built-in and are easy to maintain and migrate.